# The Maximum Eigenvalue of $F\mathrm{max(B)}F^T - FBF^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$F$ is a $b \times n$ real matrix.

$B$ is a $n \times n$ real matrix, constructed by

$B = w^T w$, where $w$ is a row vector with **strictly positive** real numbers, and clearly $B$ is a rank 1 matrix.

The operator $\mathrm{max}(B)$ is simply a $n \times n$ matrix where all the elements are filled as the maximum element in $B$.

Now, the question is, how does the eigenvalue of $F\mathrm{max(B)}F^T$ compare with $FBF^T$?

or what is the eigenvalue of $F\mathrm{max(B)}F^T - FBF^T$?

Thank you.

Comment: You can rewrite this matrix as
$$
F(\max B )F^T - FBF^T = F[\max B - B]F^T
$$
the resulting matrix has rank at most $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on $w$ :)

The eigenvalues of $uv^T$ are $v^T u, 0, \dotsc, 0$ for any vectors $u,v$. Notice that $\max(B) = ee^T \max(w)^2$, where $e = (1,\dotsc,1)^T$. So we have
$$ \lambda_\max(F\max(B)F^T) = \max(w)^2 e^T F^T F e $$
and
$$ \lambda_\max(FBF^T) = w^T F^T F w. $$

In case $w$ is a normed eigenvector to the largest eigenvalue of $F^TF$ then, we have
$$ \lambda_\max(F\max(B)F^T) = n \max(w)^2 \frac{1}{n} e^T F^TF e \le n \max(w)^2 w^T F^T F w. $$
On other hand, if $w$ is a normed eigenvector to the smallest eigenvalue of $F^T F$, then inequality flips 
$$ \lambda_\max(F\max(B)F^T) \ge n \max(w)^2 w^T F^T F w. $$
So, it depends.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand, so it all depends on the quantity of $n\mathrm{max}(w)^2$

Comment: @SngL: no, no. It depends on $w$ and the eigenspaces of $F^T F$.